# OpenGL crash in nvoglv32.dll during execution glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl

During execution `glDrawElements` happen crash in nvoglv32.dll. Immediately called `loadOpenGLObjects()` and after it invoke draw(), in which happens сrash. Seems like something went wrong with `glVertexAttribPointer`, but i don't understand what.

```cpp
GLfloat vertices[24] =
{
     -1.f, -1.f, -1.f,
     -1.f, 1.f, -1.f,
     1.f, 1.f, -1.f,
     1.f, -1.f, -1.f,
     1.f, 1.f, 1.f,
     1.f, -1.f, 1.f,
     -1.f, 1.f, 1.f,
     -1.f, -1.f, 1.f,
};
//...

void loadOpenGLObjects()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 24, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
//...
void draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 8, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Error:

Exception thrown at 0x041878C4 (nvoglv32.dll) in main.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you've to specify an [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) or you've to use [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml).

When you use [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) then you've to specify an `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Since you've 8 vertex coordinates, which are arranged to a cube, I suggest to specify and array of indices with 6 indices (2 triangles) for each side of the cube.

```cpp
GLuint indices[36] = {
    0, 1, 2,  0, 2, 3,
    // [...]
};
```

Specify the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Note the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is stated in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), do not <s>`glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`</s>:

```cpp
void loadOpenGLObjects()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 24, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_IBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * 36, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Draw the 12 triangle primitives (36 indices):

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are helped me!